# I would like to read from a list and display the matching value based on a condition

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

```
=IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN($A$9:$A),(IFS($B$9:$B=IDs!$A$3,IDs!$B$3)
```

If i use the above formula, i would have to repeat it for about 2000 times. Due to the length of my data.

Any suggestion pls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a list of ID's (IDs!B3:B) you would want to return when a match is found between the values in B9:B and IDs!A3:A, you could try

```
=Arrayformula(if(len(A9:A), iferror(vlookup(B9:B, ID!A3:B, 2, 0)),))
```

If that is not what you want to achieve, please clarify and if possible share a copy of your spreadsheet.

Comment: Thank you. This is what i wanted. :)